# How to imporve SQL Performance, Array Objects

Tags: arrays, plsql, database-performance

**ip_address_record definition**

```
create or replace type ip_object is object (ip_address varchar2(200));
create or replace type IP_ADDRESS_RECORD is table of ip_object;
```

In above, I have used Array objects, PL/SQL, to collect ipaddresses within a range.

The array works fine with small set of records, i.e. mask 124 or 120, but the performance reduces if I give huge ie mask 100 or less.
Is there a better way to approach the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use PL/SQL profiling to discover exactly what part of the code is slow.  PL/SQL Developer has a simple interface for generating and viewing profile reports.

First, open a new Test Window.  Enter the code below.

```
declare
    ips ip_address_record;
begin
    ips := pkg_cmts_ip_tools.calculateIPValues('2001::0000/124');
end;
```

Click the "Create Profilers Report" button (it looks like a little gauge).  Then execute the code.  When it's done, go to the Profiler tab.  It shows all lines of code and how much time was spent on them.  Sort by the "Total time" column to find the slowest lines.

Finding the slow code is only the first step but it's often over-looked.  Don't tune *everything*, keep a laser-like focus on the slow lines of code.  Although you may also need to step back and consider the entire algorithm.